# Derived units described with multiple 'per's

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

In a dimensional analysis problem, a rate was given textually as so many "Milliliters per Kilograms per Day". This seems ambiguous, as one could either interpret it as

A:: Ml / (Kg / Day) = Ml <sup>1</sup> * Kg <sup>-1</sup> * Day <sup>1</sup>

or

B):: (Ml / Kg) / Day = Ml <sup>1</sup> * Kg <sup>-1</sup> * Day <sup>-1</sup>

From what I've seen, the typical convention seems to be B, although it would make intuitive sense for it to be interpreted according to A, with a radically different result. So then, why is this the convention? Is the convention just to put anything preceded by 'per' in the denominator?

Further, if there were a third 'per', would every unit preceded by 'per' be implied to exist in the denominator? Or would one have to infer order of precedence?

(For those wondering, Milliliters of a drug per Kilogram of patient mass per day of prescription)

Comment: I think if the cop says “you owe 10 dollars per mile per hour you were over the limit” the hour goes in the numerator.

Comment: I agree that this ambiguity is annoying. I guess the B pattern is analogous to chained subtraction, eg 10 - 5 - 3 = 2, not 8.

Comment: I agree with both the other comments here. It is ambiguous, but in all cases I have encountered, the convention is identical to division syntax in a calculation where $a/b/c$ is equivalent to $a/(bc)$.

Comment: @Ben51 Haha, I wish! I think I see your point there. I was honestly just scrambling to think of some everyday context in which you get two 'per's, but I think you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @PM2Ring True. My background is in embedded development though, so in common C operator precedence is almost never relied upon.